# jQuery sortable connect lists - Get sorted values of list id and data-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am struggling to get values of connect lists of jQuery ui sortable

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" data-value="U1" id="L1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" data-value="U2" id="L2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" data-value="U3" id="L3">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" data-value="U6" id="R1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" data-value="U7" id="R2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" data-value="U8" id="R3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
```

javascript part

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    var dataList = $("#sortable1 li").map(function() {
      return $(this).data("id");
    }).get();
});

function submit(){
   alert(dataList);
}
```

i can't get output for `var dataList`.

The following code working for me, but I need a method to get values of attribute `data-value` along with ids?

```
var idsInOrder1 = $("#sortable1").sortable("toArray");
var idsInOrder2 = $("#sortable2").sortable("toArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get at a HTML attribute using [the `.attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(this).attr("data-value");
```

You can also use the same function to get `id`-s:

```
var dataList = $("#sortable1 li").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("id");
}).get();
// or, to get both...
dataList = $("#sortable1 li").map(function() {
  return { id: $(this).attr("id"), dataValue: $(this).attr("data-value") };
}).get();
// Now you can get id-s and data values as...
var myId = dataList[0].id;
var myValue = dataList[0].dataValue;
```

However, this usage of `.map()` and `.get()` is somewhat confusing. Yes, it works, and if you find it easier go ahead and use it, but the same effect can be achieved much more readably with [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var dataList = [];
$("#sortable1 li").each(function(idx, elt) {
    dataList.push({ id: $(elt).attr("id"), dataValue: $(elt).attr("data-value") });
});
```

Here's a demo fiddle showing all of these in action: http://jsfiddle.net/JpcXL/